# Python-get string between to characters

Tags: python

I need to one give me the string between `~` and `^`.
I have a string like this:

```
~~~~ ABC ^ DEF ^ HGK > LMN ^
```

I need to get the string between them with python.
I've tried this:

```
import re
target = ' ~~~~ ABC ^ DEF ^ HGK > LMN ^  '
matchObj = re.findall(r'~(.*?)\^', target)
print matchObj
```

But the result is:

```
['~~~ ABC ']
```

What I expect is:

```
[ABC , DEF , HGK , LMN ]
```

or

```
[^ABC , ^DEF , ^HGK , LMN ]
```

Comment: What result did you expect? `" ABC "` or `"~~~ ABC ^ DEF ^ HGK > LMN "`?

Comment: Please edit your question in a way that is useful to others.

Comment: The Golden Question to ask yourself when writing a question is: "What would the answer think?" you have provided very little information. Learn how to create a [mcve]

Comment: Please don't use this `variableNamingStyle` in python. It's against PEP 8, the official python style guide.

Comment: @CentAu i edited it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without regex:

```
>>> "".join([x for x in target if x.isalpha() or x == ' ']).split()
['ABC', 'DEF', 'HGK', 'LMN']
```

This takes space and alpha characters and creates a new string then splits it into words in a list

Here is my exact code from python 3 command line:

```
>>> target = ' ~~~~ ABC ^ DEF ^ HGK > LMN ^  '
>>> xx = "".join([x for x in target if x.isalpha() or x == ' ']).split()
>>> xx
['ABC', 'DEF', 'HGK', 'LMN']
>>>
```

Comment: it give me full source `['DOCTYPE', 'html', 'PUBLIC', 'WCDTD', 'XHTML', 'TransitionalEN', 'httpwwwworgTRxhtmlDTDxhtmltransitionaldtdDOCTYPE', 'html',` etc.... but i need `~~~~ ABC ^ DEF ^ HGK > LMN ^` this part only to be like this `[ABC , DEF , HGK , LMN ]`

Comment: I have no idea what you are doing here -- perhaps reading an html page.  At any rate, please try the 3 lines of code in my answer above

Comment: Ah, I see your edit.  First use beautiful soup to grab the text you want.  That is really another question.  Once you have `target`, then my code will work for you

Comment: If i made another question you will be able to help ?

Comment: sure, or just search for beautiful soup.  You may find someone had the same issue

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38753904/extracting-a-string-between-2-chrachters-with-python

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what result is desired, but perhaps this?

```
>>> matchObj = re.findall(r'~+(.*?)\^', target)
>>> print(matchObj)
[' ABC ']
```

Comment: result is `[' ABC ']` BUT i need `['ABC' , 'DEF' ,'HGK' ,'LMN' ] `

Comment: @dragon I edited my answer to give what you are asking here

Answer (score 0):

Your idea of using a lazy quantifier is good, but that still doesn't necessarily give you the shortest possible match - only the shortest match from the current position of the regex engine. If you want to disallow the start/end separators from being part of the match, you need to explicitly exclude them from the list of valid characters. A negated [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) comes in handy here.

```
target = ' ~~~~ ABC ^ DEF ^ HGK > LMN ^  '
matches = re.findall(r'~([^~^]*)\^', target)
print matches
```

Comment: result is `[' ABC ']` BUT i need `['ABC' , 'DEF' ,'HGK' ,'LMN' ] `

Answer (score 0):

here is my solution:

your input:

```
In [12]: target = ' ~~~~ ABC ^ DEF ^ HGK > LMN ^  '
```

replace all the symbols or delimiters with `' '` and split the result

```
In [13]: b = re.sub(r'[^\w]', ' ', target).split()

In [14]: b
Out[14]: ['ABC', 'DEF', 'HGK', 'LMN']
```

Comment: it give me full source `['DOCTYPE', 'html', 'PUBLIC', 'WCDTD', 'XHTML', 'TransitionalEN', 'httpwwwworgTRxhtmlDTDxhtmltransitionaldtdDOCTYPE', 'html']` etc.... but i need `~~~~ ABC ^ DEF ^ HGK > LMN ^` this part only to be like this `[ABC , DEF , HGK , LMN ]`

Comment: @dragon    would you be more specific about  `['DOCTYPE', 'html', 'PUBLIC', 'WCDTD', 'XHTML', 'TransitionalEN', 'httpwwwworgTRxhtmlDTDxhtmltransitionaldtdDOCTYPE', 'html']` . provide me your input and whats your expected output. so that i can help you