# Extracting a string between 2 chracters using python

Tags: python, regex, beautifulsoup

I need a Python regex to give me all the strings between `~` and `^` from a string like this:

```
~~~~ AAA ^ BBB ^ CCC > DDD ^
```

I've tried this:

```
import re
target = ' ~~~~ AAA > ^ BBB ^ CCC > DDD ^  '
matchObj = re.findall(r'~(.*?)\^', target)
print matchObj
```

But the result is:

```
['~~~ ABC ']
```

What I expect is:

```
['AAA', 'BBB', 'CCC', 'DDD']
```

or

```
['^AAA', '^BBB', '^CCC', 'DDD']
```

I want to do this because I am trying to extract text from an HTML page like this:

```
 <td class="cell-1">
    <div><span class="value-frame">&nbsp;~~~~ ABC ^ DEF ^ HGK > LMN ^</span></div>
</td>
```

Comment: Why do you have `>` also as delimiter?

Answer (score 0):

As long as you're parsing out the HTML correctly with BeautifulSoup and are just left with the contents of the span, then you should just be able to use this as a RegEx:

```
import re

target = ' ~~~~ AAA ^ BBB ^ CCC > DDD ^  '

matchObj = re.findall('(\w{3})', target)

print(matchObj)
```

**Outputs:**

```
['AAA', 'BBB', 'CCC', 'DDD']
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

```
[x.strip('~ ') for x in re.split(' *[\^\>] *', s) if x]
# ['AAA', 'BBB', 'CCC', 'DDD']
```